# How to search for a specified value within an array using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I would like to search for a specific value in an array and return its index.

html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div id="task0">Task0</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div id="task1">Task1</div>
    <div id="task2">Task2</div>
    <div id="task3">Task3</div>
    <div id="task4">Task4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $childArr = $(".col-md-6:last").children().toArray();

  $indexNumber = $.inArray("div#task3", $childArr);

  console.log($indexNumber);

});
```

Unfortunately I get -1. This means that the specified value was not found. But why do I get the -1 ? 
If i output the `$childArr` in `console.log` I get an array with this values `(4) [div#task1, div#task2, div#task3, div#task4]`.

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/39987/

Comment: Your logic is rather odd. Why bother making an array at all when you can just use `$('#task3')` to get the element you require...? If you want that element's index, use `index()`. As for your code, it doesn't work because you're looking for the index of a string in an array of jQuery objects - and those jQuery objects hold the `.col-md-6` elements anyway, not the child `#taskN` elements. It may be better if you stated what you wanted to achieve, as this does not seem optimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get `index` of element inside `.col-md-6:last` you can use `index()` function

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var index = $(".col-md-6:last #task3").index();
  

  console.log(index);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div id="task0">Task0</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div id="task1">Task1</div>
    <div id="task2">Task2</div>
    <div id="task3">Task3</div>
    <div id="task4">Task4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: okey this is very simple with the index function. This is working for me, thank you. Dziekuje

Answer (score 2):

The array is a list of HTML node elements, so you must pass the node element you want to search, not the string:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 $childArr = $(".col-md-6:last").children().toArray();
  
  $indexNumber = $.inArray($("div#task3")[0], $childArr);
  
  console.log($indexNumber);
  console.log($childArr);
});
```

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div id="task0">Task0</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div id="task1">Task1</div>
    <div id="task2">Task2</div>
    <div id="task3">Task3</div>
    <div id="task4">Task4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: By the way, what you want to achieve is pretty weird. If you tell us why you want to do this we can try to help you further.

Comment: This was just a sample code to understand how can i get a position in a div. My task are dynamic. They change in time. I have 2 columns (`.col-md-6`). In these two columns i have 8 columns (`.col-md-3`).  And in this 8 columns i have some bootstrap panels. If there are more than 10 panels so switch the rest of this panel to the other column. For this purpose i need sometime the position of the elements. is hard to describe it

Answer (score 0):

As Sylwek and Suren Srapyan answers you don't have to use toArray() to accomplish what you want. However if you want to keep this logic you can use the [findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/findIndex) function

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $childArr = $(".col-md-6:last").children().toArray();
  
  $indexNumber = $childArr.findIndex(function(child){return child.id == "task3"})
  
  console.log($indexNumber);
  console.log($childArr);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div id="task0">Task0</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div id="task1">Task1</div>
    <div id="task2">Task2</div>
    <div id="task3">Task3</div>
    <div id="task4">Task4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```